# C# Regex Match start and end

Tags: regex

How to get following result using Regex into C#.

```
string input = "<P>With effect from <<Effective Date>>, the xyz is amended as follows:</P><P>The xyz will xyz the Insured for Claims including x amount Costs or Legal Fees which arise out of or in xyz with <<Description of xyz/abc>>.</P><P>All other terms and conditions of the dddd remain unchanged.</P>";
```

Regex r = new Regex("Regular expression needed!!!");

So i am looking for following field collection using Regex (Starting with special charachter << AND ending with >>)

```
<<Effective Date>>
<<Description of xyz/abc>>
```

Comment: Have you tried.. anything? It doesn't look complicated, huh?

Comment: Have a look at regex testers like RegexBuddy. Try expressions you find from web searches. You may learn something. I know it is hard. My dream is to be a Regex Ninja. No where near yet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when questions like this are asked some effort needs to be shown instead of creating a new regular expression object stating **Regular expression needed!!!** inside the pattern. So please take consideration to state the exact problem with at least some effort on what you have attempted next time.

To get you started, you can use the following.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"<<[^>]*>>"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

**Explanation**:

```
<<       # '<<'
 [^>]*   #   any character except: '>' (0 or more times)
>>       # '>>'
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/w6uGV5)

Here are a few references to start your path of learning regular expressions.

- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Quick-Start: Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/)